# How to activate the bumblebee driver?

Tags: debian, drivers, video

I have Debian Jessie; I installed the bumblebee drivers for my video card nvidia geforce 720m.

How do I activate the drivers and to use only his nvidia card?

To install the drivers, I used the command `apt-get install bumblebee primus`

Comment: Have you checked out the instructions on https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee?

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep active the ever nvidia card, not just for one program .. I would like to use it instead of the built-in card intel :|

Comment: Your laptop might have an option in its UEFI or BIOS setup to use the GeForce card only...

Comment: Nope.....i dont see this option :|

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if your UEFI support this feature. On my laptop (Lenovo z70) I was not able to permanently enable the discrete nvidia gpu. That's right anyway, you shouldn't use the discrete video card when not needed: this would lead to heavy power consume and more heat. You should activate the discrete video card only when really needed (using optirun, or primus) for example when gaming on when working with graphics intensive softwares.

Comment: Luca non ho questa opzione nel bios :|

Comment: Please speak english so other people can learn from this question ;) By the way, this is right: the discrete video card is meant to be used only when needed! This is the same on every operating system (windows included!). Just use optirun or primus when you need to activate your discrete video card.

Comment: The problem is that the desktop can not see well. It 'a little grainy. I would always use the dedicated Nvidia card for better graphics performance.

Comment: No mate, it doesn't work that way, as I said before the discrete video card is not meant to be used as a primary video card (for a couple of reasons). If your desktop is grainy then you might have a problem with the "base" video card (Probably an Intel HD Graphic), please check if you are using the correct modules for your non-discrete GPU.

Comment: As a control if the form is right, for my gpu?
`**root@debian:/home/matteo# lspci -nn | grep VGA**
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)`

Comment: Well, I can't say if this is right xD Is this your primary GPU? if so, then yes, it is right. If you are still experiencing video problems and you are using XRender, please switch to an OpenGL renderer.